# Sort by mutual connections in social-networking iOS application with data store in firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, social-networking

I am writing an application that will help users connect to each other based on a number of attributes (i.e. location, interests, etc). I am using firebase firestore to store all of my user data, which has fields like name, hometown, interests, classes, and connections, which is a list of UUID of the users they are connected to.

When I suggest other users for a user to connect with, I want to do so by the number of their mutual connections, however this is not explicitly a field in the database, since I would have to calculate and maintain that for every user in relation to every other user. Is there a way I can use firestore to query or order by a calculated property rather than a field in the database, or another way to store the mutual connections?

I know in theory I could pull all the users from the database and then locally calculate the number of mutual connections and sort the array, but that sounds horribly inefficient.

I have searched for existing solutions such as how facebook or linkedin would suggest friends or people you might know, but I can't find any concrete answers on how they did this, but those companies are not using firestore either. I am hoping someone has had this problem in the past and can help me out.

Comment: Can you specify what *number of their mutual connections* means? Does that mean that each user has fields that store their City, Favorite Food and If they Like Cats and you want a user to connect with other users that are in the same City and have the same Favorite Food?

Comment: It is the same concept as a facebook friend, or linkedin connection. So if we are friends with 10 of the same people, the two users have 10 mutual connections. Since it seems like this might not be feasible, I am working on a sorting method more like you are describing, where it is based on how many characteristics of their profiles they have in common.

Comment: So is the question actually 'how to determine mutual connections between two people'? If so, that's very doable.

Comment: I have written code to determine mutual connections between 2 people locally. I just iterate over their lists of connections and find the common values. However, I do not think it is feasible to display users by list of mutual connection using firestore, since it sounds like I would have to pull every user from the database into my local app, then calculate how many mutual connections the current user has to each other user, then sort the list using those values.

Comment: Nope. There are a number of options for doing that but it does require structuring your data in a way that makes those queries work. It may require additional data storage and/or denormalizing some of the datasets as well. However, @frankvanpuffelen answer is on point and accepted so go with that as solution.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean about structuring the data? Other than storing the number of mutual connections for each user in relation to each other user, I am not sure how I could directly get this information from firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to perform a calculation on the data in a Firestore query. If you want to order or filter in a calculated value, you'll have to store that value in the database.

Typically you can either do this:

1. As you write the data from the client, you also update the calculated values.
2. In a Cloud Function that triggers when you write the data, and that then updates the calculated values.
3. In a Cloud Function that runs periodically, and that then updates the calculated values for all modified data.